# Task.WaitAll() let some WM_PAINT messages to be processed

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to completely block UI while I am waiting for some tasks using `Task.WaitAll()`. If the end-user interacts with the application main Form the `form1.OnPaint()` is called while waiting. We are using Winforms platform.

How can achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious. Are you calling `Task.WaitAll()` on the UI thread? And if so which thread is used for the `form1.OnPain()` method?

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: `I want to completely block UI` Why? This is exactly what a UI is *not* supposed to do.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Because in WinForms, when you process a Form/Control event, you are in the application main thread and while your event handler doesn't return, the Windows Message Pump is totally blocked, so your UI is completly blocked. Notice that some repaints can occure if some action on the form or its controls inside the code called from the event handler do immediate repaint. You should also know that Windows Vista and upper versions (7, 8) keep a current bitmap for each Window and repaint it with this backup bitmap if the application is busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you handle this is by manually disabling the UI.

If you are using winforms the simplest way is to set [`Form.Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to false, then after you have finished waiting for your tasks to finish to then re-enable it.

If you have access to async/await it would be as simple as

```
public async Task DisableFormsTillTasksComplete(Task[] tasks)
{
    this.Enabled = false;
    await task.WhenAll(tasks);
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

If you can't use async/await you may need to run the `Task.WaitAll` on a background thread so you don't block the paint events.

Comment: Sorry Scott, I want to block the paint events. Is there a typo in your last sentence or not?

Comment: I guess I did not understand your question. Can you please update your question and give a more detailed explanation of what you want blocked and what you want let through. My answer allows all UI painting to still happen but disables the program so the user can not interact with it. This is what most people are normally trying to do when they want to "block the UI". If that is not what you want you will need to be more detailed in your question as most people will assume the same as I did.

Comment: @Alberto That sounds like as if your `OnPaint` is horribly written. Maybe it would be better if you painted into a back buffer (when necessary) and always just paint from that back buffer in `OnPaint`? This way, your application would still be responsive while not doing any significant work in `OnPaint`.

Comment: @Scott: Disabling the Form, waiting for tasks to complete and enabling it back solved my problem. No WM_PAINT are processed when the form is disabled. Thanks!